# Check box status in Ext.tree.Panel

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I have a Tree Panel (Ext.tree.Panel) with children, these children turned on the option to "checked". 
I need to change the status of this "checked" (checked / unchecked) as a user action.

I have tried using the features:

```
NodeData.data.checked = false;
```

and

```
var = PN NodeData.parentNode 
PN.eachChild (function (n) {
if (idn n.id ==) {
n.set ("checked", false); 
} 
});
```

None of them worked.

Does Anyone have any idea?

Comment: you have a nice answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620613/how-to-add-checkboxes-to-ext-tree-treepanel

Answer (score 0):

Now works!

First I did it on treepanel

```
        checkchange: function (node, checked) {
            node.data.checked = checked;
            this.view.refresh();
```

So a did it to change the checkbox status

```
if (AP_NodeChecked.length>0) {
                                                for (var u = 0; u < AP_NodeChecked.length; u++) {
                                                    var NodeData = AP_NodeChecked[u];
                                                    //Teste para desligar o nível 3
                                                    if (NodeData.data.ID_DADO_NIVEL_03 == rec.data.items[u].data.id) {
                                                        ArvorePai.fireEvent('checkchange', NodeData, false);
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }
```